How can I export this deconstructed data from Matlab into a single file?
I have located a public data set that I want to analyze but it is stored currently in Matlab. I am not a Matlab user and would love to get a tip/solution for exporting this data in a useable format. I have 30 days with a trial to figure it out. To me the data structure is extremely awkward, not sure if that's from the author or just how Matlab works. So there are hundreds of what I would call tables, that look like this:

Then these tables are referenced in what I think might be called a cell array(?) which looks like this:

Each table has a name, also stored separately in what looks like a plain text file containing a list:

And the column names aka "variables" for each table is another text file with a list that looks very similar to the table names.
Then, I have multiple sets of these structures that, in the end, I will concatenate together into a single file. So, overall I want the reconstructed file to look like this:

I messed around for a while with writecell(), writetable(), cell2table() and just didn't get anywhere. Even just exporting one single table, which I could then loop and put it back together with Python exports in "column major" format, which isn't useable. So I'm looking at hundreds of cut,paste,edit cycles to clear up this mess.
I have been looking in vain for the "export" button but there are no buttons, only Matlab script. Maybe someone out there has the magic incantation that can put this humpty table back together again :-)
Thanks for any assistance!

You don’t need to export from MATLAB. You can read the data file in Python too, there’s a package for that. Or you can use Octave, which is a free MATLAB look-alike. What language are you comfortable using?

"So there are hundreds of what I would call tables", it might help your documentation searching to call these by their proper name, which is "matrices" or "arrays". One approach would be to convert them into actual MATLAB tables using array2table, into which you can pass the array and the column names, then you can use writetable to write it to a csv or whatever other format relatively easily.
